# How do I make APScheduler run a python script?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am trying to automate a script by making it run every day at 5:00 p.m. I made a python file that contains the following code:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day_of_week='mon-sun', hour=17)
def scheduled_job():
    print('This job is run everyday at 5:00 p.m.')

sched.configure(options_from_ini_file)
sched.start()
```

That seems to work, but I need it to actually run a script that is in the same directory as the schedule file. Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running with subprocess -

```py
import subprocess
out = subprocess.check_output(
         "python file.py", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True
      )

print(out)
```

You might have to do a fancier command, like if you are in a virtualenv, you might want to add it to your path, or explicitly say which python to run (`path/to/python`).